# Web scraping with python request and beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape all the articles on this web page: https://www.coindesk.com/category/markets-news/markets-markets-news/markets-bitcoin/

I can scrape the first article, but need help understanding how to jump to the next article and scrape the information there. Thank you in advance for your support.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Content:
    def __init__(self,url,title,body):
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.body = body

def getPage(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

# Scaping news articles from Coindesk

def scrapeCoindesk(url):
    bs = getPage(url)
    title = bs.find("h3").text
    body = bs.find("p",{'class':'desc'}).text
    return Content(url,title,body)

# Pulling the article from coindesk

url = 'https://www.coindesk.com/category/markets-news/markets-markets-news/markets-bitcoin/'
content = scrapeCoindesk(url)
print ('Title:{}'.format(content.title))
print ('URl: {}\n'.format(content.url))
print (content.body)
```

Comment: Can you please add a link or something like that to the printed output?

Comment: Title:
Topping Out? Bitcoin Bulls Need to Defend $9K

URl: https://www.coindesk.com/category/markets-news/markets-markets-news/markets-bitcoin/

Having hit seven-day lows below $9,000 this morning, bitcoin is looking decidedly weak.
[Finished in 0.4s]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that every article is contained within a `div.article` to iterate over them:

```
def scrapeCoindesk(url):
    bs = getPage(url)
    articles = []
    for article in bs.find_all("div", {"class": "article"}):
        title = article.find("h3").text
        body = article.find("p", {"class": "desc"}).text
        article_url = article.find("a", {"class": "fade"})["href"]
        articles.append(Content(article_url, title, body))
    return articles


# Pulling the article from coindesk
url = 'https://www.coindesk.com/category/markets-news/markets-markets-news/markets-bitcoin/'
content = scrapeCoindesk(url)
for article in content:
    print(article.url)
    print(article.title)
    print(article.body)
    print("-------------")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find_all` with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from collections import namedtuple
import request, re
article = namedtuple('article', 'title, link, timestamp, author, description')
r = requests.get('https://www.coindesk.com/category/markets-news/markets-markets-news/markets-bitcoin/').text
full_data = soup(r, 'lxml')
results = [[i.text, i['href']] for i in full_data.find_all('a', {'class':'fade'})]
timestamp = [re.findall('(?<=\n)[a-zA-Z\s]+[\d\s,]+at[\s\d:]+', i.text)[0] for i in full_data.find_all('p', {'class':'timeauthor'})]
authors = [i.text for i in full_data.find_all('a', {'rel':'author'})]
descriptions = [i.text for i in full_data.find_all('p', {'class':'desc'})]
full_articles = [article(*(list(i[0])+list(i[1:]))) for i in zip(results, timestamp, authors, descriptions) if i[0][0] != '\n ']
```

Output:

```
[article(title='Topping Out? Bitcoin Bulls Need to Defend $9K', link='https://www.coindesk.com/topping-out-bitcoin-bulls-need-to-defend-9k/', timestamp='May 8, 2018 at 09:10 ', author='Omkar Godbole', description='Bitcoin risks falling to levels below $9,000, courtesy of the bearish setup on the technical charts. '), article(title='Bitcoin Risks Drop Below $9K After 4-Day Low', link='https://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-risks-drop-below-9k-after-4-day-low/', timestamp='May 7, 2018 at 11:00 ', author='Omkar Godbole', description='Bitcoin is reporting losses today but only a break below $8,650 would signal a bull-to-bear trend change. '), article(title="Futures Launch Weighed on Bitcoin's Price, Say Fed Researchers", link='https://www.coindesk.com/federal-reserve-scholars-blame-bitcoins-price-slump-to-the-futures/', timestamp='May 4, 2018 at 09:00 ', author='Wolfie Zhao', description='Cai Wensheng, a Chinese angel investor, says he bought 10,000 BTC after the price dropped earlier this year.\n'), article(title='Bitcoin Looks for Price Support After Failed $10K Crossover', link='https://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-looks-for-price-support-after-failed-10k-crossover/', timestamp='May 3, 2018 at 10:00 ', author='Omkar Godbole', description='While equity bulls fear drops in May, it should not be a cause of worry for the bitcoin market, according to historical data.'), article(title='Bitcoin Sets Sights Above $10K After Bull Breakout', link='https://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-sets-sights-10k-bull-breakout/', timestamp='May 3, 2018 at 03:18 ', author='Wolfie Zhao', description="Goldman Sachs is launching a new operation that will use the firm's own money to trade bitcoin-related contracts on behalf of its clients.")]
```

Comment: seems to throw me an error for the [article(*[*b, *c]) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Martin598 the unpacking syntax is for Python3. I will add a way for Python2

Comment: Thank you Ajax1234 for your support!